# Simple 'Hello World' type setup of TextAngular fails

Tags: angularjs

Trying to use TextAngular module with a simple example as possible, but it does not look correct.

First the editor textarea is only 1 line high. When I try to use the editor I can edit mulitple lines, but lines after the first line then "merges" with other html elements below the editor-area (see plunker how it looks).

Like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div text-angular ng-model="message"></div>
  </div>
  Some text below...
</body>
```

and with controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['textAngular']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Default message";
});
```

See it all in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/t1YIpwLjPo7yNfVTWPAt?p=preview

What I am doing wrong for this highly simple example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this issue also.  Need to add the following class to your styles:

```
  .ta-editor {
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin:20px 0;
 }
```

Comment: Agreed.  Took me about half an hour to figure out the issue.

Comment: Here's a link to some older instructions that contain the code above: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Getting-Started-v1.1.x

Answer (score 1):

You can add this link instead :

```
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textAngular/1.5.0/textAngular.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ng-model use ng-bind as your are binding to a div and want the message to go inside the div

```
ng-bind = {{}}
```

or to see two way binding in action:

```
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div>{{message}}</div>
      <div ng-bind="message"></div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="message">
  </div>
```

No need to inject the text-area in as a module. If you want to do something like that then:

```
angular.module('myApp',[textArea]);

angular.module('textArea', [])
    .controller('myController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Default message";
    });
```

Comment: Although not an answer to my question, I like any suggestions for improvement :) But regarding textarea, I have not injected textArea, only textAngular, was that a typo?

Comment: Ah i see the difference in names... same situation though... you inject modules not attributes. This attribute could be the start of a directive though!

Comment: And for the future if u get into TDD using the module approach makes unit testing so much easier as you can include only the modules you would like to test.